# Почему компилятор выдает ошибку?

Tags: c#

```
if (winner == true)
            {
                Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(layout2));
                StartActivity(nextActivity);
                string win = "";
                if (hod)
                    win = "O";
                else
                    win = "X";
                var txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
                txt.Text = win + "Победил";
                hod_count = 0;
                hod = true;
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `FindViewById` может вернуть `null` это нормально. Ну а почему именно - из данного фрагмента мы понять не сможем. Подозреваю что не там вообще этот код написан.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку выдает не компилятор.

Вам нужно получить Ваш `TextView` по какому-то условию. Из Вашего примера кода TextView ищется с помощью метода `FindViewById`.

\телепат mode on\ Скорее всего, вы использовали `VisualTreeHelper`. \телепат mode off\

Пройдите по шагам в Вашем методе поиска UserControl, и все станет ясно.

Comment: что ?..........

Comment: @Jevgewa создайте точку останова `Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(layout2));` и далее посмотрите пошагово на каком этапе у вас все летит в тартарары. Очевидно что `FindViewById` возвращает `null`. Вам осталось выяснить почему. По всей видимости передается несуществующий ID.